# Deferred Deeplink not working in facebook ads, but working on testing through facebook notifications as mentioned in the documentation

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, facebook-ads, deferred-deep-linking

I have implemented Facebook Deferred Deeplink Inside the application. When I test my ad from the Ad Helper in Facebook, the deferred link is successfully transmitted. But when I click the ad preview from the Facebook app, the deferred deep link is null.

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this) { appLinkData ->
}
```

Using below sdk
`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:14.1.0'`

please help to here whats need to do from myside. thanks

Comment: have the same issue but im using flutter ...